# Como desplegar de forma correcta router-outlet del children dentro del parent

Tags: angular, angular5

Mi idea comenzó cuando pensé en usar una vista de inicio de sesión para proteger toda mi aplicación (usando guardias) y forzar al usuario a iniciar sesión si desea navegar por el componente principal (planet.data en este caso).

Así que utilicé lazy loading (no relevante) para planet.module y canActivate dentro de planet-routing.module.ts, pero después no pude navegar a planet-detail porque la ruta no podia coincidir con el segmento de URL. 
Error desplegado: *Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'rovers/411634'*

"Resolví" este problema agregando una ruta de planet-detail como hijo de 'rovers'. Ahora viene la parte cuando coloco el router-outlet dentro del template de planet-data y todo está bien hasta que hago clic en una imagen del planeta para navegar a esa identificación de imagen. La imagen de planet-detail está justo debajo de la vista de datos del planeta. ¿Qué me estoy perdiendo? Me gustaría que guien en la dirección correcta por favor. O alguna posible solucion

Comportamiento esperado: navegar al ID de la imagen (solo esa ruta) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

// planet-data.component.html

```
<div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
        <div class="ui-g-8">
            <app-title *ngIf="pics"></app-title>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-4">
            <app-dropdown-menu (selected)="onSelect($event)"></app-dropdown-menu>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12">
        <app-no-image class="margin" [cam]="true" [start]="true" *ngIf="!pics"></app-no-image>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-planet-view class="image" [pics]="pics"></app-planet-view>    
</div>
<app-loader></app-loader>
```

// planet-detail.component.html

```
<div class="ui-g">
    <app-image [picById]="picById"></app-image>
</div>
```

// planet-routing.module.ts

```
const planetRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PlanetDataComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: PlanetDetailComponent,
                canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
        ],
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
    ];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(planetRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PlanetRoutingModule {}
```

// app.routing-module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'rovers', loadChildren: './planet/planet.module#PlanetModule' },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/home' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

// app.component.html

```
<header><app-header></app-header></header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<footer><app-footer></app-footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> La imagen de planet-detail está justo debajo de la vista de datos del planeta.

Se carga debajo justo porque tienes el `<router-outlet>` debajo de tu lista de planetas.

Tu `planet-data.component.html` debería tener únicamente el `<router-outlet>` y tus rutas deberían tener un componente a cargar como en el ejemplo:

```
const planetRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PlanetDataComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: 'PlanetaComponent'
          },
          {
            path: ':id',component: PlanetDetailComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
          },
        ],
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
    ];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(planetRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PlanetRoutingModule {}
```

Puedes ver que se declara `path: ''` dos veces: en la primera es donde carga el `<router-outlet>` y se declaran los children. En el segundo es un componente a cargar dentro de ese router.

Es en ese segundo donde deberías tener el HTML de planet-data.component.html, donde tienes tu listado de los planetas. (Quitando la línea del router).

Comment: Funciona, entonces al declarar una ruta con ID dentro de children tengo que siempre declarar un componente base? es decir, en este caso 'rovers' y luego ':id' ? Puedo ver que no se puede hacer eso mismo en la ruta padre.